# Passing NSString between methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, nsstring

I've got myself some of a newbie problem.

I got this method to determine the zip code where the iPhone is located, based on GPS coordinates. Reverse Geocoding. My method works, I know this, since it has no problem writing out the correct zip code to a label.

But I need this zip code to be stored in a string that I can use inside a method I use to compose a SMS.

Anyone can help me with that?

Tell me if an source code is necessary! (Just not currently sitting on my work comp)

Clearly i've been misunderstood, should have posted som code.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;


    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            **postalCode** = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                            placemark.postalCode];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

Here i try to save the zip code inside the NSString named postalCode (highlighted with "**")

I try to load it again in sms composer

```
-(void)displaySMSComposerSheet
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;


    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            postalCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          placemark.postalCode];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1220", nil];
    picker.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dog %@", (placemark.)postalCode];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

only prints out in the SMS window:
Dog (null)
And i'm sure i have the coordinates, they get printed out in the output.

Hope this helps to understand the question better

Comment: u need to retain the `postalCode` when u assign it after getting the zip code from google apis..

Comment: are both on same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `postalCode` across viewControllers, you could just save it to `NSUserDefaults`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // ...
    NSString *postalCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                            placemark.postalCode];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:postalCode forKey:@"postalCode"];
    // ...
}
```

and load it again

```
-(void)displaySMSComposerSheet
{
    // ...
    NSString *postalCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"postalCode"];
    // ....
}
```

**Edit:** Are you sure that `placemark` and `postalCode` are already set (i.e. -`locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` has been called)? If `displaySMSComposerSheet` is called before a location was determined, this behaviour is normal.

**Edit2:** From your code, it looks like you forgot to tell the `locationManager`to start updating locations. Add the following to `viewDidLoad`:

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Seems like i got the same answer

The (placemark.)postalCode the "("")" was only to show i've tried both things. only postalCode still returns (null) inside the SMS

Comment: You mean like i have done in this example?
Just copied the whole class into pastebin
postNr = postalCode (It's just the danish word)
http://pastebin.com/ZVQ1dNWH

Comment: Updated my answer again, see `Edit2`

Comment: Am really gratefull you are taking the time! But that didn't help either, still just returning (null) and i have NO idea how to solve this..

Comment: But do you see the log messages from `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` (you could also set a breakpoint to ensure that this is called)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't get called...
I need to check the methods again and see what i'm missing, will keep this post updated :)

**UPDATE**
I added 
locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

and now the locationManager is called, but still returning (null)

Comment: I did what you wrote and it came to null?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
picker.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dog %@", postalCode];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)displaySMSComposerSheet
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation;


    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            postalCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          placemark.postalCode];
            [self showMailComposer:postalcode]; // method call
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];



}

-(void)showMailComposer:(NSString *)postalCode{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1220", nil];
    picker.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Dog %@",  postalCode];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer.
I've tried this, it just won't open the display the sms. 
Posted the complete ViewController.m file on pastebin.
http://pastebin.com/ZVQ1dNWH